# Are questions about beta software OK for Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, beta-phase, windows-8

Is it OK to ask questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10553373/575530) about debugging the Metro IE10 Consumer Preview on Win8 Consumer Preview over on Stack Exchange?

On the one hand I'm stuck and it feels like something others may get stuck on too; but on the other hand problems experienced on beta software may be too short-lived for their solutions to be of lasting use.

Comment: I'll add an answer to cover sites on "Stack Exchange" meaning the larger concept of 82+ sites as opposed to "Stack Exchange" meaning Stack Overflow - the heavy hitting, main programming site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So long as the question are on-topic and the software in question is widely available (by which I mean not a closed beta or such), they are fine.

Comment: Thanks Oded, these are widely available so I'm OK.

Answer (score 3):

You will want to be cognizant of the specific site's FAQ when you ask a question on beta software. Some love them, others prefer to not discuss things that are not shipping. You are right to reference the "short term" downside and will see that the more widespread the software and the platform, the more likely it will be of use to ask and answer a question on beta software.

If the FAQ on a specific site does not address this - you can always raise that question on the site specific meta if you want a green light before posting.

---

The [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) site is one where beta in general is off topic even though there are some exceptions (like Siri and the Messages beta)

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq
- https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=beta