# Reason for reopening an old moderator closed question

Tags: discussion, moderators, vote-to-reopen

I understand for recently closed and edited questions no need for an explicit reason for reopening is needed.

However, how did [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11873798/256431) get reopened when the last edit was 6 months ago, two days after the product it was referring to a beta of was released (according to the Eric Lippert comment)? It was also moderator closed as "too localized" by the last editor, CasperOne.

Should moderator closed questions need more effort to be reopened? (Where "effort" may be providing a reason or something else.)

Edit: I see my "how" was taken a little literally. I really meant "why did the old closed question get reopened by 5 people?"

Nevertheless, sanity has been restored, and it seems that is the way people want it to have to be manually done.

Comment: I think you're mistaking re-opening with un-deleting a post. If a moderator deletes a post, the community can not vote to un-delete it, but this is not the case with closing. If a moderator votes to close a post, the community can still vote to re-open it.

Comment: @TimPost No, unless the question I'm referring to has been deleted and it is not mentioned in its revision history. The closure just made sense to me and I can't determine why five people thought it should be reopened.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132275/are-questions-about-beta-software-ok-for-stack-exchange

Answer (score 9):

**No**

Moderators can close and re-open posts instantly, but theirs is not necessarily the last word. If the community feels that a moderator made a mistake, or is unhappy with the closure, delete etc, they can reverse the decision.

In fact, this should be encouraged more. Too often users are afraid of "going against" a moderator, but since they need 4 other people to agree in most cases, moderators will happily step back if the majority disagree with their decisions.

I do not believe we now need to add re-open reasons. The fact that 5 people, and/or a moderator, looked at the question and decided that it was good enough to be re-opened is reason enough. Also, nothing prevents the question from being closed again.

<sub>I am a retired SU moderator, and have often had to reverse decisions I made in the past because of this. My opinion about moderators backing off is my own and may not be shared among the current moderators</sub>

Comment: I understand we need to allow the moderators to be overridden. My question actually morphed as I wrote it: originally I didn't notice it was a moderator close -- to me the close just made sense -- and I was asking if any old closed question should be able to be reopened without a reason given.

Comment: @MarkHurd Then just flag it or vote for it to be closed again? Why do we need reasons. There is nothing wrong with a question being closed and re-opened multiple times, unless those closes and re-opens interfere with the community.

Comment: That is what I have done. It just seemed like there may have been a reason I've missed.